# How does volatile-ttl work in Redis?

Tags: redis

In Redis.conf, various key eviction strategies are presented, with some basics on how they work.

I believe I want to use `volatile-ttl`, but I can't find sufficient information on how it works.

On the face, it's clear; keys with nearest expire times go first.  What if Redis evicts **all** keys with an expire time?  What then does it choose next to evict, assuming that it still needs to keep evicting to stay under `maxmemory`?

```
# MAXMEMORY POLICY: how Redis will select what to remove when maxmemory
# is reached. You can select among five behaviors:
#
# volatile-lru -> remove the key with an expire set using an LRU algorithm
# allkeys-lru -> remove any key according to the LRU algorithm
# volatile-random -> remove a random key with an expire set
# allkeys-random -> remove a random key, any key
# volatile-ttl -> remove the key with the nearest expire time (minor TTL)
# noeviction -> don't expire at all, just return an error on write operations
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will throw an out of memory error

```
 127.0.0.1:6379[2]> info memory
# Memory
used_memory:2091560
used_memory_human:1.99M
used_memory_rss:4022272
used_memory_rss_human:3.84M
used_memory_peak:2097296
used_memory_peak_human:2.00M
total_system_memory:16712204288
total_system_memory_human:15.56G
used_memory_lua:37888
used_memory_lua_human:37.00K
maxmemory:2097152
maxmemory_human:2.00M
maxmemory_policy:volatile-lru
mem_fragmentation_ratio:1.92
mem_allocator:libc
127.0.0.1:6379[2]> set q1 as;ldkfjaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaajjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjsssssssssssssssssssssssasdfasdlfkjhasdkjfhas;djkfhsad;kfjas;dhflaskjdfhlksajdhf;asjdhf;sadkjf;jsadhflkjshadf;kjahsdlfkjhasdlkjfhsak;djfhas;kdjhfsajkdfhkasj;dhf;aksjdhf;jasdfh;jksadhfkjas;dhfk;jasdfh;asjdfh;sjdahfjkasdhf;kjsadhf;kjsadhf;jashdf;jsdahfjk;hads;fkjhsad;fjhasd;jfhas;dfhsa;dhfsa;jdkfhasdkjfhlskajdh;kjhf;akjshdf;asjkdhf;asdjkhf;sjadhf;jsadhf;jsdhf;jsahdf;jsahdf;jhasd;fjhsad;jfha;sdjfhsad;jfhsadj;fhas;jdkfhsad;kjfh;asjdhf;ajsdhf;jasfdhas;ldkfjaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaajjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjsssssssssssssssssssssssasdfasdlfkjhasdkjfhas;djkfhsad;kfjas;dhflaskjdfhlksajdhf;asjdhf;sadkjf;jsadhflkjshadf;kjahsdlfkjhasdlkjfhsak;djfhas;kdjhfsajkdfhkasj;dhf;aksjdhf;jasdfh;jksadhfkjas;dhfk;jasdfh;asjdfh;sjdahfjkasdhf;kjsadhf;kjsadhf;jashdf;jsdahfjk;hads;fkjhsad;fjhasd;jfhas;dfhsa;dhfsa;jdkfhasdkjfhlskajdh;kjhf;akjshdf;asjkdhf;asdjkhf;sjadhf;jsadhf;jsdhf;jsahdf;jsahdf;jhasd;fjhsad;jfha;sdjfhsad;jfhsadj;fhas;jdkfhsad;kjfh;asas;ldkfjaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaajjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjsssssssssssssssssssssssasdfasdlfkjhasdkjfhas;djkfhsad;kfjas;dhflaskjdfhlksajdhf;asjdhf;sadkjf;jsadhflkjshadf;kjahsdlfkjhasdlkjfhsak;djfhas;kdjhfsajkdfhkasj;dhf;aksjdhf;jasdfh;jksadhfkjas;dhfk;jasdfh;asjdfh;sjdahfjkasdhf;kjsadhf;kjsadhf;jashdf;jsdahfjk;hads;fkjhsad;fjhasd;jfhas;dfhsa;dhfsa;jdkfhasdkjfhlskajdh;kjhf;akjshdf;asjkdhf;asdjkhf;sjadhf;jsadhf;jsdhf;jsahdf;jsahdf;jhasd;fjhsad;jfha;sdjfhsad;jfhsadj;fhas;jdkfhsad;kjfh;asas;ldkfjaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaajjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjsssssssssssssssssssssssasdfasdlfkjhasdkjfhas;djkfhsad;kfjas;dhflaskjdfhlksajdhf;asjdhf;sadkjf;jsadhflkjshadf;kjahsdlfkjhasdlkjfhsak;djfhas;kdjhfsajkdfhkasj;dhf;aksjdhf;jasdfh;jksadhfkjas;dhfk;jasdfh;asjdfh;sjdahfjkasdhf;kjsadhf;kjsadhf;jashdf;jsdahfjk;hads;fkjhsad;fjhasd;jfhas;dfhsa;dhfsa;jdkfhasdkjfhlskajdh;kjhf;akjshdf;asjkdhf;asdjkhf;sjadhf;jsadhf;jsdhf;jsahdf;jsahdf;jhasd;fjhsad;jfha;sdjfhsad;jfhsadj;fhas;jdkfhsad;kjfh;as
(error) OOM command not allowed when used memory > 'maxmemory'.
```

Answer (score 5):

The `volatile-ttl` policy will evict all volatile keys (meaning keys set to expire) based on their TTL in ascending order. When no more volatile keys are left - i.e. all remaining keys are non-volatile - and assuming that RAM pressure continues, no further eviction will take place and Redis will reply with OOM (out of memory) error.

Comment: Isn't it _TTL in descending order_ . From http://oldblog.antirez.com/post/redis-as-LRU-cache.html " volatile-ttl remove a key among the ones with an expire set, trying to remove keys with short remaining time to live."